# How to use php to retrieve all the file name in a specific folder

Tags: php

say, in my webserver there is a folder call upload_files
then one of my php page should grab the all the file name in that folder
i have googled but so far the file name returned is only the page the user browsering
thanks

Comment: use `glob("upload_files/*")`. It returns an array of all the files in it (including folders). Too short for an answer and unchecked.

Comment: Please explain more precise what you are trying to do, and what you alredy got. some code would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of retrieving folder content like `glob`, `scandir`, `DirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, personaly I would recommend you to check DirectoryIterator as it has big potential.

Example using `scandir` method

```
$dirname = getcwd();

$dir = scandir($dirname);

foreach($dir as $i => $filename)
{
    if($filename == '.' || $filename == '..')
        continue;

    var_dump($filename);
}
```

Example using `DirectoryIterator` class

```
$dirname = getcwd();

$dir = new DirectoryIterator($dirname);

foreach ($dir as $path => $splFileInfo)
{
    if ($splFileInfo->isDir())
        continue;

    // do what you have to do with your files

    //example: get filename
    var_dump($splFileInfo->getFilename());
}
```

Here is less common example using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` class:

```
//use current working directory, can be changed to directory of your choice
$dirname = getcwd();

$splDirectoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirname);

$splIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $splDirectoryIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($splIterator as $path => $splFileInfo)
{
    if ($splFileInfo->isDir())
        continue;

    // do what you have to do with your files

    //example: get filename
    var_dump($splFileInfo->getFilename());
}
```

Comment: +1 for scandir, cause everyone else is suggesting glob for some bizarre reason

Comment: I guess they have strong Linux background

Comment: $dir = scandir($dir); will cause undefine variable

Comment: Sorry, made a typo, should be `$dir = scandir($dirname);` where $dirname is your upload directory

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon:

```
glob("upload_files/*")
```

returns an array of the filenames.

but BEWARE!  bad things can happen when you let people upload
stuff to your web server.  building a save uploading script
is quite hard.

just an example: you have to make sure that nobody can upload
a php-file to your upload-folder.  if they can, they can
then run it by entering the appropriate url in their browser.

please learn about php & security before you attempt to do this!

Answer (score 0):

The following will print all files in the folder `upload_files`.

```
$files = glob("upload_files/*");
foreach ($files as $file)
    print $file;
```