# Trying to parse files, receiving an error that has to do with SplFileInfo

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, symfony

I am saving an image with the current User object and even though i'm not yielding any wanted results. I am trying to parse an array of files, in that array, I am trying to get the object key that is named `filename`.

I currently have 2 images in this file array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => SplFileInfo {#219 ▶}
  1 => SplFileInfo {#220 ▶}
]
```

Each array key has an object and in that object I am looking for the filename key:

`filename: "oIWVAvlOyG9yMzhhvTFoYX2wGNTa2pEth7gb228Z.png"`

If it really matters, my code is on a controller on Laravel 5.4:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userImagesPath = public_path().'\\storage\\'.$user->email;
        $userImagesArray = File::allFiles($userImagesPath);
        $contents =[];
        $fileNameArray = [];
        foreach ($userImagesArray as $file){
            $contents[] = $file;
            foreach ($contents as $fileName){
                $fileNameArray[] = $fileName->filename;
            }
        }
        dd($fileNameArray);
        return view('sharmutaView')
            ->with('user', $user);
    }
```

I am getting an error: `Undefined property: Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo::$filename`, which is clearly telling me I ain't parsing right.

Comment: Seems to be correct according to the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php). Does it work when you use the getFilename function? http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userImagesArray` is the array you provided?

Try this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userImagesPath = public_path().'\\storage\\'.$user->email;
        $userImagesArray = File::allFiles($userImagesPath);
        $fileNameArray = [];
        foreach ($userImagesArray as $file){
                $fileNameArray[] = $file->getFilename();
            }
        }
        dd($fileNameArray);
        return view('sharmutaView')
            ->with('user', $user);
    }
```

Comment: That's correct and it should other people find the original here:
[link to original]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813643/how-to-use-php-to-retrieve-all-the-file-name-in-a-specific-folder